# #1062 - Duplicate entry '19' for key 'PRIMARY'

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1062

I have the following table in MySQL version 5.5.24

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `bookings` (
`booking_id` int(11) NOT NULL ,
  `class_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=22 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;



INSERT INTO `bookings` (`booking_id`, `class_id`, `user_id`) VALUES
(19, 3, 5),
(21, 6, 5);



CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users` (
`user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `username` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `firstname` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `lastname` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(255) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=6 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;


INSERT INTO `users` (`user_id`, `username`, `firstname`, `lastname`, `email`, `password`) VALUES
(4, 'another', 'Anne', 'Other', 'another@gmail.com', '1234'),
(5, 'rbirney', 'Rosanne', 'Birney', 'rosanne.birney@gmail.com', '1111');


ALTER TABLE `bookings`
 ADD PRIMARY KEY (`booking_id`), ADD KEY `class_id` (`class_id`,`user_id`), ADD KEY `user_id` (`user_id`);



ALTER TABLE `classes`
 ADD PRIMARY KEY (`class_id`);


ALTER TABLE `users`
 ADD PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`);


ALTER TABLE `bookings`
MODIFY `booking_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,AUTO_INCREMENT=22;


ALTER TABLE `classes`
MODIFY `class_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,AUTO_INCREMENT=11;

ALTER TABLE `users`
MODIFY `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,AUTO_INCREMENT=6;


ALTER TABLE `bookings`
ADD CONSTRAINT `fkBookingClass` FOREIGN KEY (`class_id`) REFERENCES `classes` (`class_id`),
ADD CONSTRAINT `fkBookingUser` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `users` (`user_id`);
```

I am getting the following message

> #1062 - Duplicate entry '19' for key 'PRIMARY'

anyone have any ideas?

Comment: My guess is that as part of your debugging process you ran your script twice and didn't clean up your data in between, so you created two records with a booking_id of 19.

Answer (score 1):

In SQL it is not allowed to use the same value for a primary key twice. (value = 19)
Primary keys are always unique.

Comment: Its more general than that. The SQL standard defines primary key as unique and not null. Other database implementations have the same constraints.